# the scale problem of libviso2

Tags: ros, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I use my own images to run libviso2, but the result is not very well. There existed a scale problem in both mono and stereo program. There are two sample rates in my experiments. One is 5 m/frame, another is 1 m/frame. The results showed between two consecutive frames, the distance in stereo system are about 10 meters and 2 meters respectively. However, in mono system the distance are about 1 meters and 0.2 meters respectively. How can I solve it?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98941/the-scale-problem-of-libviso2/) by [Lily](https://answers.ros.org/users/8556/lily/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In mono odometry, the scale is a parameter you have to fix. From two consecutive frames  it's impossible to compute scale.
Using stereo image pairs for each frame helps reduce error and provides additional depth and scale information.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0